# I contributed to cleanup the documentation. Rejected as invalid. I don't agree

Tags: django, django-forms

Django 1.10.1

My ticket: https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/27280

Simulated situation: https://bitbucket.org/Kifsif/formsets/commits/f5e05aa61bcfe4be776bd1acc436589d27c78d29

The ticket is closed. The answer was: "Without initial data, the formset will output 1 empty form".

Could you help me understand who is right.

Earlier in the documentation there was:

```
ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, validate_min=True)
```

In this case how can a formset with data for 3 forms produce one empty form?

In the initial we have meat for 2 forms. And how can it fill the third one?

In my opinion this is a surrealism somehow. I suppose that in vain he closed my ticket. But I'm too green. Maybe I'm wrong.

And if I'm right, what to do? Create new ticket?

Comment: I've closed this as a duplicate because you already asked a similar question yesterday. If you disagree with the reason for closing the Django ticket, then you can add a comment - please don't open a new ticket.

Comment: In this case, I agree with the decision to close the ticket. The example in the `can_order` docs is  `ArticleFormSet = formset_factory(ArticleForm, can_order=True)`, which **does not** use `min_num`. The example then uses initial data for the formset so that we get non-empty rows when we print the formset. When we instantiate the formset again, it's good practice to use the same initial data again, so that `formset.has_changed()` works.

Comment: Pardon. In the modelled example at bitbacket there is no min_num. And even this wouldn't change anything: there is much meat for data than for initial. So, I still think that the ticket is closed in vain.

Comment: I mentioned `min_num` because your question includes an example that uses `min_num`. Sorry, I don't understand your latest comment, or what the example on bitbucket is meant to show.

Comment: It imitates the can_delete. It produces forms in get method. And one can catch in post method what comes from the user. In other words, one can mark forms for deletion. But even if min_num is there. How can min_num=3 influence? I gave data for 3 forms. So, how min_num can influence? Can it pruduce an empty form? Anyway, I'll edit the initial post.

Comment: I think discussing `min_num` is going off topic for this question - as I said, the example in the docs for `can_order` and `can_delete` do not even use `min_num`.

Comment: Now that you've removed `min_num` from your question, I see where you might be confused. I'll have one more go at explaining: It's the first formset `formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[...])` which would print a single empty form if you removed the `initial` argument. As you say, you could leave out `initial` from the second formset `formset = ArticleFormSet(data, initial=initial)`. However this is bad practice, because it would break `formset.has_changed`.

Comment: formset.has_changed was illustrated much earlier. And after that several formsets have already been created without initial data. And now you think it is a bad practice not to insert initial data. Have I understood you correctly?

Comment: If you create a formset with initial data in the GET request `formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[...])` then you should use the same initial data in the POST request `formset = ArticleFormSet(data, initial=[...])`. It is bad practice to leave out initial data from the POST request if you included it in the GET request. If the GET request didn't have initial data, then you don't need it in the POST request.

Comment: Hm. I can't catch what are you talking about. If you are about the documentation, there is no GET or POST request there (in the article about  fomrsets of course). If you are about my example, then I didn't use initial anywhere: either in get or in post methods.

Comment: You wouldn't normally define a data dictionary `data={...}` in your view, you would use `request.POST`. So in the examples in the docs, you can think of `formset = ArticleFormSet(initial=[...])` as representing the GET request and `formset = ArticleFormSet(data, initial=[...])` as representing the POST request.

Comment: I have never thought of initial as substitution of get. I just want to improve documentation. How this documentation will be used is not our business. They can use it in get. So what. I just want to isolate can_delete / can_order. Look, you have studied in the university or somewhere what a model is. Not django model. But model in science, engineering. A model is an abstraction from where everything unnecessary is removed. This "initial" is not illustrating the target mechanism. This means that it should be excluded from the model. Example in the documentation is a model of a real case.

Comment: I'm going to step back from the comments. Sorry my explanations were not more helpful.